# WinPhone C# Send Id to a window with selector.SelectedItem

Tags: c#, windows-phone, longlistselector, itemssource

Hi i gave a list (named source) of objects (dog(Id, Name)) to my selector:

```
selector.ItemsSource = source.Select(obj => obj.Name).ToList();
```

This code works and show dog names. Now i want to send Id of selected dog to the next windows which show my doggydetails, i try something like this but it don't works:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/categ.xaml?doggyDetails=" + selector.SelectedItem.Select(obj => obj.Id),   UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: is this a LongListSelector or LongListMultiSelector?

Comment: Each name is unique. It's a LongListSelector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a list of names to as the item source and then expect to get a `SelectedItem.Id` back. This can't be done..

EDIT (haven't seen you have a dictionary as your source)

I would create a class

```
class Dog
{
     public string Name {get;set;}
     public Guid Id {get;set;}
}
```

Try this:

```
 var dogs = from s in source
            select new Dog
            {
                 Name = s.Name,
                 Id = s.Id
            }

selector.ItemsSource = dogs.ToList();
```

And then you get the item as

```
var itemId = (selector.SelectedItem as Dog).Id
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/categ.xaml?doggyDetails=" + itemId,   UriKind.Relative));
```

You will have to bind your textbox or whatever you have to the Name property in xaml though, something like:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <TextBlock Text = {Binding Name}/>
         </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: If i do this: selector.ItemsSource = source.ToList(); the selector don't show me the names of dogs.

Comment: What kind of selector are you using?

Comment: Thanks you very much for your help. I use LongListSelector. I have "null exception reference"to this line: var itemId = (selector.SelectedItem as dog).Id i don't understand why. I try to print each elements of dogs which fill selector and there aren't null element.

Comment: What you could do is attach a SelectionChanged event in xaml and then use the 'sender' to get your item. It would be something like 'var item = (sender as LongListSelector).SelectedItem' and then you can to the casting to get your element

Comment: I will use this: 'var item = (sender as LongListSelector).SelectedItem' Thank you all for taking the time to help me :)

Comment: If my answer really helped you I would really appreciate it if you mark it as the answer :) and welcome to SO :)

Comment: It's my first post on stackoverflow i don t know where i need to click to mark it as answe^^ When i click on the arrow it said me: vote up require 15 reputations

Comment: under the up down arrows you see a checkmark. when you click it this post is awarded the correct answer :)